# Rails-ier way to get hours in a day?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

I needed to know how many hours were in a Daylight Savings Day and ended up with this:

```
>(Time.zone.parse('31-10-2021').end_of_day - Time.zone.parse('31-10-2021').beginning_of_day)/3600
=> 24.99999999999972
```

Is there a Rails-ier way? something like `Date.parse('31-10-2021').hours` or `Date.parse('31-10-2021').hours_in_day` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Rails 6.1 you can use [ActiveSupport::Duration#in_hours](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_hours):

```
hours = Time.zone.new(2021, 10, 31).then do |day|
  (day.beginning_of_day-day.end_of_day).in_hours
                                       .round.to_i # optional 
end
```

In older versions of Rails you can do:

```
hours = Time.zone.new(2021, 10, 31).then do |day|
  ((day.beginning_of_day-day.end_of_day) / 1.hour).round.to_i
end
```

Comment: On a side note: Don't parse dates unless you actually have to (when dealing with user input).